# Array return type problem in PHP

Tags: php, apache-flex

```
function showFields($selClient) 
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM project WHERE projectid = $selClient");
        $values = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
        {
            $values[] = array($row['clientname'],$row['prospect'],$row['salesperson']);
        }
        return $values;

  }
```

When i return the values to Flex, i am not able catch individual elements. When i trace i get all values stored in a single array...

I am slightly confused...,.

```
var editField:Array = event.result as Array; 
        Alert.show(editField[0]);
```

This returns all the values in the Array, instead of the 0th element.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You'll get all values as an array because you are returning an array.

Comment: you are putting an array into an array, so what do you expect?

Comment: How can i print each individual values

Comment: you are welcome, please vote for the answer and finish it by setting to answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do:
Alert.show(editField[0][0]);

if i understand it correctly...

you need to iterate over two arrays (two levels)

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are only returning specific columns, why select them all? This will function will return the same data and as it only selects what you need, will be faster. In this case the select is so simple that the time difference will be virtually 0, but it's a good habit to get into for when your db queries start getting more complex.

```
function showFields($selClient) 
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT clientname, prospect, salesperson FROM project WHERE projectid = $selClient");
    $values = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $values[] = $row;
    }
    return $values;
}
```